# Cypress 12.14 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Tags: cypress, typeerror, undefined

I've encountered a very strange problem with Cypress where its unable to 'get' any element. All my commands work until the code gets to cy.get.

*My code:*

```
cy.get('#username').type('blueUser');
```

*Error:*

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set').
```

[image]

This is really puzzling because I know the element exists because I used older versions of Cypress and it worked just fine. I even tried the Cypress Studio (Record and Playback) and it created identical code to my own but still threw that same error. Help please !

Stack trace pasted into comments:

at get (xxxxxxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:148433:10)
at $Command.overridden (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159898:21)
at cyFn (xxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160714:19)
at  (xxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159444:15)

From previous event:
at CommandQueue.runCommand (xxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159410:8)
at next (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159610:19)
at next (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypr

Comment: There's not quite enough to go on - if you can hit the "View stack trace" we can see where it originates.

Comment: My guess it's failing to log something, since a failure in the actual test usually leaves a much better message.

Comment: Also, what version on Cypress was it working on?

Comment: @Achtung Its running version 12.14 and the stack trace:
    at get (xxxxxxxxxx.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:148433:10)
    at $Command.overridden (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159898:21)
    at cyFn (xxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160714:19)
    at <unknown> (xxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159444:15)
From previous event:
    at CommandQueue.runCommand (xxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159410:8)
    at next (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:159610:19)
    at next (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/__cypr

Comment: The error indicates you have a query overwrite in the test - please post that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for adding the stack trace. As mentioned in comments, the stack is indicating a `Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery()` is being used which has used the wrong form of callback.

The docs [Custom Queries](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-queries#Usage) show

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery('get', function (originalFn, ...args) {
  return originalFn.apply(this, args)
})
```

but if instead you use

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery('get', (originalFn, ...args) => {  // arrow function
  return originalFn.apply(this, args)
})
```

you get errors caused by `this` being undefined.

The warning is given in the docs:

> The query API relies on `this` to set timeouts, which means that `callbackFn` should always use `function () {}` and not be an arrow function (`() => {}`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out but my overwriteQuery comes from an external npmjs plugin called 'cypress-if' and I found the code you are referring to and I don't actually use the arrow function anywhere. Here is an example code snippet.

Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery('get', function (get, selector, options) {

  // can we see the next command already?
  const cmd = cy.state('current')
  debug(cmd)
  const next = cmd.attributes.next
  return get(selector, options)
})

Comment: `cypress-if` only works with versions before Cypress version 12, due to internal changes. You will have to use an earlier version of Cypress, or write your own `cypress-if`, or tackle branching logic a different way.